# Is there a way to tag API operations once they are created

Tags: azure-api-management

Several API operations were imported from OpenAPI YAML file using Terraform, however part of the API operations were under `x-ms-paths:` and import hasn't picked tags which were defined within YAML.

I found that this was raised as an issue for Microsoft: [MS issue](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/39263032-tags-not-importing-when-defined-in-x-ms-paths).

Wondering is there a way to workaround this problem and to assign existing tags for the API operations which are under `x-ms-paths:` once they are imported?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure CLI to update the tags.

[az apim update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/apim?view=azure-cli-latest#az_apim_update)

```
az apim update --name
           --resource-group
           [--tags]
```

> --name -n
> The name of the api management service instance.
>
> --resource-group -g
> Name of resource group. You can configure the default group using az configure --defaults group=.
>
> --tags
> Space-separated tags: key[=value] [key[=value] ...]. Use "" to clear existing tags.

Comment: My question was related to tagged API operations. The link you provided describes the control of the APIM tags in general.

Comment: OK. Azure CLI supports tags only on API Level not on operation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/apim/api?view=azure-cli-latest#az_apim_api_update
Also the REST API does not support it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-12-01/apioperation/update


So you have to update the OpenApi definition. For running a script, you have to clone the API Management repository

Comment: The problem, that OpenAPI definition tagging works when:

```yaml
paths:
  /myoperation:
    get:
      tags:
        - MyTag
```

And does nothing when:

```yaml
x-ms-paths:
  '/myoperation?param0={Param0}&param1={Param1}:
    get:
      tags: 
        - MyTag
```